# What is file ID - Streamtape API

Tags: javascript, cloud-storage

I am trying to use streamtape's API [link](https://streamtape.com/api). It isn't well defined. To get a download ticket I have to send a request to `https://api.streamtape.com/file/dlticket?file={file}`,

That `file` needs to be the file id of the file but I don't have any idea what it should be from this link:

`https://streamtape.com/v/PkOXR0WyyXIRMw/Cars_1.mkv`

Like When I try `PkOXR0WyyXIRMw` It gives this Error `{"status":500,"msg":"Too high server load","result":null}`

And when I try the name, this comes `{"status":200,"msg":"OK","result":{"ticket":"Cars_1.mkv~~1634220008~n~~0~aHgT37V4VL73PTav","wait_time":20,"valid_until":"2021-10-14 14:10:09"}}`

But when I try to get a download link of it with `https://api.streamtape.com/file/dl?file={file}&ticket={ticket}`, This comes `{"status":403,"msg":"Download Ticket not valid","result":null}`.

I am making requests with Javascripts's Fetch API. Also I cant find the api-login in my account settings:
[image]

I wanna know What's the File id of streamtape files. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to file manager in streamtape.
[image]
then right click on uploaded video after copy video url.
[image]
then you can get video url like bello.
https://streamtape.com/v/l4K3pBlRKAC7g2M/SHATIR.MAID.2023.mkv.mp4
This video file id is l4K3pBlRKAC7g2M

Comment: Improve formatting of the answer & change the size of images (too big)!

Answer (score -1):

This happened with me too, For api log in & key password, you need to click on API/FTP Credentials in account settings tab at down-side of the page in mobile chrome browser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).